# MySql memory engine do not check on update foreign key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

After making a few tests, I found that foreign keys on MEMORY engine miss one of the checks for consistency.

To explain better, here a similar example in InnoDb

```
CREATE TABLE testInnoDb1 (
    c1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE testInnoDb2 (
    c1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (c1) REFERENCES testInnoDb1(c1) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO testInnoDb1 (c1) VALUES (42);
INSERT INTO testInnoDb2 (c1) VALUES (42);
-- INSERT INTO testInnoDb2 (c1) VALUES (64); -- This will fail
-- UPDATE testInnoDb2 SET c1=128; -- This will fail
```

And the same with MEMORY

```
CREATE TABLE testMem1 (
    c1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

CREATE TABLE testMem2 (
    c1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (c1) REFERENCES testMem1(c1) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

INSERT INTO testMem1 (c1) VALUES (42);
INSERT INTO testMem2 (c1) VALUES (42);
-- INSERT INTO test2 (c1) VALUES (64); -- This will fail
UPDATE testMem2 SET c1=128; -- This should fail?
```

My question is: Why the update consistency is not maintained with the memory engine? Is that a bug or it is for any real reason? Any reference to a known bug for this?

As additional info, I am using for development the repository release on my Linux which is still 15.1 (5.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does not currently support foreign key constraint checking:

> MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual
>
> [13.1.17.3 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.htmls)
>   Foreign Keys and Other MySQL Statements
>
> > **Important**
> >     For storage engines that do not support foreign keys (such as MyISAM), MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key specifications.
>
> [Chapter 15 Alternative Storage Engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engines.html)
>   Table 15.1 Storage Engines Feature Summary
>
> ```
> Feature              MyISAM  Memory  InnoDB  Archive  NDB
> Foreign key support  No      No      Yes     No       No
> ```
>
> [15.3 The MEMORY Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html)
>   Table 15.4 MEMORY Storage Engine Features
>
> ```
> Foreign key support     No
> ```

PS From 15.3 re InnoDB (which has FKs) vs MEMORY (which does not):

> Performance Characteristics
>   Despite the in-memory processing for MEMORY tables, they are not necessarily faster than InnoDB tables on a busy server, for general-purpose queries, or under a read/write workload.